# The cell I press in my table sends the label for the previously pressed cell

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am new to Swift and I have this interesting problem.

I am trying to send the label of a table cell when I segue to another view controller where I print it. The problem is that it is printing the label of the cell that was pressed previous to this press.

Here is the code in the main view controller that passes the label:

```
// When a user taps on a cell on the tableView, it asks for a tag name for that image.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("Cell \(indexPath) selected")

    // Get cell image.
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! ImageFeedItemTableViewCell
    imagePass = currentCell.itemImageView
    labelPass = currentCell.itemTitle

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Send image to GreetingViewController.
    if segue.identifier == "GoToGreeting" {
        var greetingvc = segue.destination as! GreetingViewController
        greetingvc.passedImage = imagePass
        greetingvc.passedLabel = labelPass

    }
}
```

and here is the relevant code in the view controller that receives the passed label:

```
var passedImage: UIImageView? = nil
var passedLabel: UILabel? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    print(passedLabel?.text)

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is your `perform segue` method?

Comment: I removed it because it was sending the segue twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `prepare(for:sender:)` gets called before `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` when you hook up that segue in the storyboard.

What you can do is just use the `sender` parameter of the `prepare(for:sender:)` method to get the information you need at the right time. When a segue is triggered by a cell, as it seems to be in your case, then that cell will be the `sender` passed into the the `prepare` method. So, you could do something like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Send image to GreetingViewController.
    if let cell = sender as? ImageFeedItemTableViewCell, segue.identifier == "GoToGreeting" {
        var greetingvc = segue.destination as! GreetingViewController
        greetingvc.passedImage = cell.itemImageView
        greetingvc.passedLabel = cell.itemTitle
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked great! I hadn't thought of the order of operations like that. Still getting used to the object oriented stuff.